# Check three integer values for type and print result

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
public static int ReadInt1(){
    int x;
    try {
    x = (int)System.in.read();
    return x;
    }catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString()); 
        return 0; 
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString() + "\nReturned value: -1"); 

        return-1; 
    }
}    
public static int ReadInt2(){
    int y;
    try {
    y = (int)System.in.read();
    return y;
    }catch (IOException es) { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + es.toString()); 
        return 0; 
    } catch (NumberFormatException es) { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + es.toString() + "\nReturned value: -1"); 
        return-1;
    }
}
  public static int ReadInt3(){
   int z;
    try {
    z = (int)System.in.read();
    return z;
    }catch (IOException ed) { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ed.toString()); 
        return 0; 
   } catch (NumberFormatException ed) { 
   System.out.println("Exception: " + ed.toString() + "\nReturned value: -1"); 
   return-1; 
   }    
}  
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println("Type a number1");   
int x = ReadInt1();
System.out.println("Type a number2");   
int y = ReadInt2();
System.out.println("Type a number3"); 
int z = ReadInt3();
 if (x-3*z !=0){
    System.out.println((3*(x-2)*y)/(x-3*z));
 }else throw new ArithmeticException();
}
}
```

What I want to do is type 3 ints, check if they are ints and then print the result of the (3*(x-2)*y)/(x-3*z) after checking the denominator. The problem is that after I type the first number 1. if its not an int the programm prints the 'Type a number2' and 3 , doesnt allow me to give any numbers and prints a result. 2. if it is an int it prints 'Type a number2'
'Type a number3' and then lets me type a number. I also dont know how does the programm come up with those results.

Answer (score 0):

This method `System.in.read();` reads just one byte. e.g when you type

```
1<enter>
```

The `1` and `<enter>` are one byte each.  `1` will be 49 which is the ASCII code for `1` and the byte will be 10 which is the ASCII code for ^J or return/enter.

Most likely you wanted to read a number as text and parse it as an `int` value, like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type a number1");   
int x = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Type a number2");   
int y = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Type a number3"); 
int z = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(3.0 * (x-2) * y / (x - 3 * z));
```

Note: I use the value `3.0` so when you do the division, you get a floating point value instead of doing an integer division.

Comment: Well, here's what i changed and it works: `byte b2[] = new byte[16];
        String str2;
        try {
        System.in.read(b2);
        str2 = (new String(b2)).trim(); 
        return Integer.parseInt(str2); `

Comment: @FloatsAreFun This would only work if you pause between entering integers.  It wouldn't work if you redirected input from a file. Reading the console as binary when really you want text, is going to be error prone and/or overly complicated no matter what you do.